# How to convert a Java-Array to a JavaCV-Matrix?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

Is there a simple way to convert a Java-Array like `double[][]` to `CvMat`in JavaCV?

I think in OpenCV you can say `cv::Mat Table(8, 8, CV_32FC1, table);`, where `table` is a 8x8 array. But in JavaCv it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, now I've found out, that JavaCv can put single Arrays to a matrix. So I can convert my 2d-Array to a 1d-Array and put this into the matrix with `Matrix.put(array)`.